# Eucalyptus cloud volume related error log

Tags: cloud, eucalyptus

I have created a volume and when I tried to attach the volume, I run this command:

```
euca-attach-volume -i i-3C66428A -d /dev/sdf vol-639C3E6C
```

After theat when I tried `euca-describe-volumes` it says failed. I have checked my cc.log but it seems like it has no error in it. So where should I look for to keep track of volume related error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check for errors on the NC (/var/log/eucalyptus/nc.log) where the instance is running as well as the SC logs (/var/log/eucalyptus/cloud-output.log) ?

To know more on the exact workflow that happens behind the scene when you request a volume attach in Eucalyptus please refer to following

https://github.com/eucalyptus/eucalyptus/wiki/Storage-Controller

For a more detailed guide around EBS in Eucalyptus 3.3.0 specifically please refer to following link

https://github.com/eucalyptus/architecture/wiki/ebs-3.3-Volume-Attach-Detach-in-Eucalyptus-3_3_0

Hope this is useful.

Cheers!
Deependra

Comment: Got it! But why should I have an error in NC :/ I thought cc handles it! :/